# Writing to an NIO socketchannel throws IOException: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, nio

I have a NIO program that listens to two IPC connections. The IPC is based on UnixDomain Sockets and uses the jnr-unixdomainsocket library which allows me to wrap the UDS with selectable ServerSocketChannels and SocketChannels. I use this library since I want to run the program with non-blocking IO, but blocking on a linux select call. I wrote a class called NIODriver which implements the channel accept and read functions(code below). 
Iam running two instances of the NIODriver class(code below), one bound to each IPC Pipe. My main class obtains a single instance of a Java selector and registers the two instances of the NIODriver's ServerSocketChannel with the selector. They are initially registered with Accept interest. The program then calls select and waits there. When the external program connects, the main class obtains the instance of the NIODriver associated with the pipe and calls its acceptConnection method.This creates the SocketChannel instance inside it which gets registered on the same selector with Read interest. This happens with both instances since I have two external programs one connecting to each pipe.
 One external program (lets call it A) continuously pumps data (a 12 byte packet) to the NIO program. The select keeps firing and calling NIODriver's channelRead method which reads the data, then gets a reference to the other NIODriver instance and calls its update()method. The update method writes the data out to the second external program (say B). When I run this in a loop, I occasionally get IOException: resource temporarily unavailable.
 Code for NIODriver class below

public class NIODriver {

```
int did;
String name;
String udsName;

UnixSocketAddress sockAddress;
UnixServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
Selector selector;
UnixSocketChannel channel;
ByteBuffer inbuf;
ByteBuffer outbuf;

int ctr = 0;

public NIODriver(int id, String name, String pipename) {
    this.did = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.udsName = pipename;

    this.sockAddress = new UnixSocketAddress(new File(udsName));
    inbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12*100);
    outbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12*100);
}

public void setSelector(Selector sel){
    this.selector = sel;
}

public boolean openConnection(){
    try {
        serverChannel = UnixServerSocketChannel.open();            
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(sockAddress);  
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT, this);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NIODriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean acceptConnection(){
    try {
            System.out.println("accepting connection");                
            channel = serverChannel.accept();
            channel.configureBlocking(false);
            channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, this); 
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("acceptConnection failed");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return false;
        }
}

public int channelRead(){
    try {                
        int n = channel.read(inbuf); 
        if(n == -1)throw new DriverDisconnectedException("Channel.read returned -1");
        /* Important: Call flip before checking number of readable bytes */
        inbuf.flip();
        int num = inbuf.remaining();            
        if(num<12){
            /* Going to return since there is not enough bytes. Set buffer
                back to read mode before returning.
            */
            inbuf.compact();
            return 0;
        }

        int id = inbuf.getInt();            
        double dval = inbuf.getDouble();
    inbuf.compact();
    if(dval == 0){
    System.out.println("Read value="+dval); 
    }

    for(NIODriver obs: gt.observers){
        obs.update(id,dval);
    }                   

        return 0;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return 0;
    } catch (DriverDisconnectedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NIODriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return -1;
    } 
}


public void update(int id, double val){
    try {
        outbuf.putInt(id);
        outbuf.putDouble(val);
        outbuf.flip();
        channel.write(outbuf);
        outbuf.compact();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NIODriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post skeleton code to demonstrate the sequence of events a bit more clearly?

Comment: And the stack trace? And edit your question to remove the incorrect part?

Comment: Thank you for your attention Neil and EJP. Apologies for my long delay. I have completely rewritten the question. Please review.